# Firefox add-on host permission error on tab with PDF file

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I couldn't find this exact situation elsewhere:  I have a custom add-on, which I'm loading temporarily via the developer menu.  In the manifest file, I'm asking for a lot of permissions already:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "homepage_url": "...",
  "permissions": [
    "file:///*",
    "*://*/*",
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "bookmarks",
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon.svg"
    },
    "default_title": "..."
  }
}
```

I have a background script only at the moment, however a small content script snippet gets injected:

```js
(function() {
  browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
    let executing = browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      code: "window.getSelection().toString()"
    })
    ...
    try {
      let selection = await executing
      ...
    } catch(exception) {
      console.log(exception)
    }
    ...
  })
})()
```

The purpose is essentially to get the current selection as text (for now) in order to later upload it to a bookmarking service of sorts.

However, when I have a tab open with a PDF file (`https://www.example.com/file.pdf` or `file:///home/foo/file.pdf`), the call of the content script to `window.getSelection().toString()` fails, with the following error:

```
Error: Missing host permission for the tab
```

Is this expected and I'm just missing a particular permission (and which one would that be)?  Or is it unexpected and possibly worthy of a bug report?

Also, the call works in the developer console, which is why I'm thinking I'm really missing permissions somehow.

Comment: The PDF viewer is a built-in UI page so it can't be injected.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1454760

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm and paul-heil, very useful to have the actual bug to track!